# crud operation play framework example using angular js

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.0

I am beginner in play framework I want sample crud operation in play framework 2 integrated with  angular js at front end side (view mode)
  please  give me suggestion thanks in advance

```
                        <!doctype html>
                 <!-- <html lang="en" ng-app="fruitsApp"> !-->
                 <html lang="en" ng-app="App">
                <head>
         <title>Angular Sample App</title>
          <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
        var App = angular.module('App', []);
             App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
           $http.get('fruits.json')
          .then(function(req){
                      $scope.todos = req.data;            
             });
          });
      </script>
      </head>
           <body ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
         <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
              {{todo.text}} - <em>{{todo.done}}</em>
           </li>
        </ul>
       </body>
      </html>
```

i want integrate  angular js with play what will be i write  $http get  in above code  for play controller class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to perform crud operations with AngularJS is to use the module [ngResource](http://www.masnun.com/2013/08/28/rest-access-in-angularjs-using-ngresource.html). 
It provides an abstraction of the module $http to consume a rest API.
(of course you need to have a working rest API provided by Play Framework)

Comment: how it possible to integrate with play